# Importing csv file into django and getting list index out of range error

Tags: python, django, web, backend

I'm trying to upload a csv file into my django projects and save data into my model.
The problem is i'm getting list index out of range but the data is uploaded correctly and saved into model.
Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

this is my method in views.py :

def admin_upload(request):
    template = "admin_upload.html"

```
prompt = {
    'order': 'CSV fichier  cef, cin, nom, prenom, group, module, note_1, note_2, note_EFM'
}

if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, template, prompt)

csv_file = request.FILES['file']

if not csv_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
    messages.error(request, 'Please upload a CSV file')

data_set = csv_file.read().decode('UTF-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)
next(io_string)
for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'):
    _, created = Note.objects.update_or_create(
        cef=column[0],
        cin=column[1],
        nom=column[2],
        prenom=column[3],
        group=column[4],
        module=column[5],
        note_1=column[6],
        note_2=column[7],
        note_EFM=column[8]
    )

context = {}
return render(request, template, context)
```

my model :

class Note(models.Model):

```
cef = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
cin = models.CharField(max_length=30)
nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
prenom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
group = models.CharField(max_length=10)
module = models.CharField(max_length=30)
note_1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
note_2 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
note_EFM = models.CharField(max_length=5)
```

When i upload a csv file the data get uploaded but i get list index out of range error:

```
IndexError at /import/
list index out of range
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/import/
Django Version: 3.0.2
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
list index out of range
Exception Location: C:\Users\HP\djangopro\IstaWebSite\ista_larache\web_ista\views.py in admin_upload, line 122
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\Envs\projectf_f\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\HP\\djangopro\\IstaWebSite\\ista_larache',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\Scripts',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\users\\hp\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\Envs\\projectf_f\\lib\\site-packages\\odf']
Server time:    Tue, 17 Mar 2020 23:33:59 +0100
```

My CSV file:

cef, cin, nom, prenom, group, module, note_1, note_2, note_EFM

15474620, la561651, zaed, Aqqdd, dqzx, Asdxdd, 10, 20, 12

Comment: Please add your CSV file

Comment: Done! I added my csv file.

Comment: I think your problem might be that you are converting the file to a string. Why don't you try reading the file directly?